# Since $f(x)$ is a pdf, we must have that $(1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma) \ge 0$ for all values of $x$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$? Incorrect reasoning?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, location-scale-family

**Theorem 3.5.1** of *Statistical Inference*, second edition, by Casella and Berger, says the following:

> **Theorem 3.5.1** Let $f(x)$ be any pdf and let $\mu$ and $\sigma > 0$ be any given constants. Then the function
> $$g(x \mid \mu, \sigma) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma} f\left( \dfrac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \right)$$
> is a pdf.
>
> **Proof:** To verify that the transformation has produced a legitimate pdf, we need to check that $(1/\sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma)$, as a function of $x$, is a pdf for every value of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ we might substitute into the formula. That is, we must check that $(1 / \sigma) f((x - \mu)/\sigma)$ is nonnegative and integrates to $1$. Since $f(x)$ is a pdf, $f(x) \ge 0$ for all values of $x$. So, $(1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma) \ge 0$ for all values of $x$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$. ...

I don't think this proof is correct. The argument that, since $f(x)$ is a pdf and so $f(x) \ge 0$ for all values of $x$, we must have that $(1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma) \ge 0$ for all values of $x$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$, completely neglects the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of $f$. It seems to me that $x$ being in the domain of $f$ does not imply that $(x - \mu)/\sigma$ is in the domain of $f$.

Comment: (One-dimensional) PDFs are usually assumed to have all of $\mathbb{R}$ as domain, simply being zero where "necessary", in which case there is no problem. How do Casella & Berger define PDFs in general?

Comment: Whether or not you consider a pdf to have a domain that is a proper subset of $\mathbb R,$ it can *always* be extended to a function on $\mathbb R$ by setting it to zero where it is otherwise undefined.  This fact is immediate from the definitions, so it's unlikely that it would be explicitly pointed out in most textbooks.

Answer (score 4):

Stephan remarked it [correctly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638372/since-fx-is-a-pdf-we-must-have-that-1-sigmafx-mu-sigma-ge-0#comment1193169_638372). The [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) can be the whole real line $\mathbb R$ and if it is a proper subset of $\mathbb R, $ then the density is $0$ outside the support. C&B argued $(1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma)$ can be either positive (when in support) or $0$ (when outside support), so it covers the whole range $\mathcal X. $

In general, if $\mathcal G$ is a group of transformations and $\mathcal P, $ the family of probability distributions, is *invariant* with respect to action of $\mathcal G $ on $\mathcal P, $ then it means for every $\mathrm P\in\mathcal P, ~g\in\mathcal G, $ there exists $\mathrm P_g\in\mathcal P, ~\mathrm P_g:=g\circ_{\mathcal G} \mathrm P$ such that for every Borel-measurable function $h, $ $$\mathbf E_\mathrm P[h(gX) ]=\mathbf E_{\mathrm P_g}[h(X) ].\tag 1\label 1$$

When $\mathcal G:=\mathcal G_{\mathrm{ ls}}, $ the group of location-scale transformations on $\mathbb R, $ one can show in light of $\eqref 1$ that for $g\in\mathcal G, ~g=(\mu, \sigma), ~gx=\sigma x+\mu, $

$$\mathbf E[h(gX) ]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\sigma x+u) f(x) ~\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x) (1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma) ~\mathrm dx,$$ that is, $gX$ is absolutely continuous with density $(1 / \sigma)f((x - \mu)/\sigma). $

---

### Reference:

$\rm[I]$ Elements of Distribution Theory, *Thomas A. Severini,* Cambridge University Press, $2005, $ sec. $5.6, $ pp. $155-157.$